# Ubuntu 16.10 LAN Speed

Tags: networking, ethernet, lan

I am running a 1Gb wired LAN in my office, currently using mostly Windows 8.1 computers. When transferring files between Windows computers, I average 106 MB/sec (~850 Mbps) which is acceptable for a Gb LAN.

I want to switch to Linux computers, and I just added a new Ubuntu 16.10 system to the network. It too is running a 1 Gb wired Ethernet connection. However, the fasted speed I've been able to achieve is only 55 MB/sec (440 Mbps) when the Ubuntu machine is receiving, and 35 MB/sec (280 Mbps) when sending from the Ubuntu machine.

The hardware should be fast enough for higher transfers- both machines running recent i7 CPUs, generous RAM, and I am transferring files between two SSD drives, through a Netgear Nighthawk R8500 router.

Any suggestions on how I can make the Ubuntu machine faster on the LAN? I have followed a couple suggestions that I found online but have not had any speed increases at all.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes browsing websites seems to be somewhat “clunky” with images not loading correctly, large latency values between your computer and the DNS resolving server, and online cache issues. This may be a sign that your internet provider's DNS are not up to the task, so you may have to change to an alternative option. The two most popular DNS server alternatives are the Google Public DNS and the OpenDNS, but there are a lot more free to use alternatives as well.

Here's how to change to the Google Public DNS on Ubuntu-based distributions. Open your network settings and hop onto the “Advanced Settings”. This will open up a new window where you will find the “IPv4 and IPv6 Settings” tabs. Navigate to both and change the “Method” from Automatic (DHCP) to Automatic (DHCP) Addresses only. Then insert “8.8.8.8” on the DNS servers box of the IPv4 tab, and “2001:4860:4860::8888” on the IPv6 tab. Now, click the “Save” button and you're done.
To test whether your new DNS settings are working properly or not, insert any fixed IP address that points to a website and see if it gets correctly resolved. Insert “91.189.94.40” on your browser address bar and if it gets resolved to ubuntu.com, then you have done things right. You may always revert to your default DNS by leaving the DNS servers box blank and setting the method back to “Automatic (DHCP)”. You can also benchmark your new DNS by using the namebench open source DNS benchmarking utility, and see how much faster your internet browsing really got. It is worth noting that changing your DNS also improves your privacy, security, and may potentially open up access to geoblocked content.

Answer (score 0):

The answer about changing DNS server should not impact on LAN speed as far as I know....

I got the speed problem from time to time. Usually, I found the Network card driver to be responsible for this. First step, boot Ubuntu from a live-CD (or flash drive) and see if you can manage better speeds. If you are lucky, there's more than one driver for your network card. Try another one.

Lastly, use another card (PCI-express slot prefered) and see if you are still limited in speed.

There is no magic wand to wave away those pesky-hard-to-diagnose network problems.

Good Luck !